# Is there a Cloud Management Platform that can control/manage hosted, open source Linux VMs?

Tags: api, virtualization, virtual-machine

Is there a CMP that can manage QEMU/KVM VMs without OpenStack?  Is there a CMP that can integrate with oVirt?

I want to manage a hybrid cloud (AWS and on-premises VMs) with the same application.  I want an API for automation and a GUI to allow non-technical users to create VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [Proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com)?  It supports KVM, LXC. It has an [API](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_API) and a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenNebula](https://opennebula.org/) toolkit is much simpler than the OpenStack one and provides all of the features you need. It supports KVM out of the box. The other requirements are also covered:

- manage hybrid cloud: See  https://docs.opennebula.org/5.8/advanced_components/cloud_bursting/index.html
- API for automation: See https://docs.opennebula.org/5.8/integration/index.html
- GUI for non-technical users: see https://docs.opennebula.org/5.8/operation/sunstone_enduser/cloud_view.html#using-the-cloud

Answer (score 0):

I think we use vSphere [here](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/info/slug/datacenter_cloud_infrastructure/vmware_vsphere/6_7). We have 71 VMs. User permissions are very granular so that means I only have access to the VMs I need to have access to. Multiple users are supported.